# I want to study the analysis on Heisenberg group, Please recommend me a comprehensive textbook.

Tags: heisenberg-group

I want to study the properties of  Sobolev space on the Heisenberg group.
For example, if the horizontal gradient of $f$ is bounded, why is $f$ lipschitz continuity?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.